# Let user pick someone from the database PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Suppose that we execute a query based on a users criteria. And after this query has been completed I present an array to the user with all the people that fit in to his criteria.

Like so:
[image]

Note, that I've added a button on the right of each person, and I'm struggling with figuring out how to know which person has been selected since this array is dynamic.

I post the code for this (but, it's quite long...)

```
$sql1 = "SELECT DISTINCT pid FROM open_position, person
                 WHERE open_position.cid=$s_cid AND (person.prof=open_position.field 
                    OR person.studies LIKE '%open_position.studies%'
                    OR person.skillz LIKE '%open_position.skillz%' 
                    OR person.languages LIKE '%open_position.pref_languages%')";

        if ($result1 = mysqli_query($dbconn, $sql1)){

            $data = array();
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
                $data[] = $row["pid"];
            }

            mysqli_free_result($result1);

            ?>
            <table style="float:center" class="table_center">
                <tr>
                    <th id="top_left">pid</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Studies</th>
                    <th>Skills</th>
                    <th>Languages</th>
                    <th>Hired</th>
                    <th id="top_right">Available From</th>
                </tr>

            <?php
            $size = count($data);
            $i = 0;
            while ($i < $size) {
                $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE pid = '$data[$i]'";
                if ($result2 = mysqli_query($dbconn, $sql2)) {
                    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <?php 
                                    echo $row2['pid'];
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php 
                                    echo $row2['first_name'];
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php
                                    echo $row2['last_name'];
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php
                                    echo $row2['address'];
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php
                                    echo $row2['studies'];
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php
                                    echo $row2['skillz'];
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php
                                    echo $row2['languages'];
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php
                                    if ($row2['hired'] == "1"){
                                        echo "YES";
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        echo "NO";
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php
                                    echo $row2['availability'];
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" class="button" name="hire" value="HIRE
                                <?php 
                                    $_SESSION['hired_pid'] = $data[$i];

                                ?>"></input>
                            </td>
                        <tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                }

                $i = $i + 1;
            }
            ?></table>
            <?php
        }
```

Any ideas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok to achieve this. For the button itself you can add it to redirect to a url with person id in it.. something like this.

```
<a href='hire.php?pid=<?=$row2['pid'];?>'><input type='button' value='hire' /></a>
```

In hire.php grab the person id, and do whatever you wanted to do. This can be done in many ways depending on your requirement. It is just a sample idea.

Comment: But how will I be able to save selected pid? So i can **mark** the selected person as hired?